# SSH refusing connection after changing default port

Tags: server, ssh

currently I'm handling 2 server (A and B). 
In server A I installed Ubuntu 12.10. I changed the SSH port into 1198 and it works fine. In server B it has been installed with Ubuntu 11.04. I tried to change the port number into 1198 as well but it refused the connection when I tried to connect again using Putty.

I change the SSH configuration on /etc/ssh/sshd_config and I did restart the SSH using sudo service ssh restart. I was thinking its because of firewall allowed port but the firewall shows inactive when I run sudo ufw status.

Any idea why this can happened?

Comment: Can you run a portscan against machine B? `sudo nmap -sV <host>`

Comment: Also, 11.04 no longer receives updates and 12.10 will be EOL come April, so you really should switch to a current Ubuntu version. For servers, I generally recommend 12.04, which is a LTS version and will be updated until April 2017.

Comment: Could you add results of `sudo netstat -lntp | grep ssh`?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I needed to run iptables to open up the port:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport $PORTNUMBER -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

For the changes to be applied, you need to restart the service `sshd` and not necessarily the pc (but you might as well).

you can do that by running

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I forgot to set virtual server rule on my router. Don't forget to associate port with host under NAT.